# How do I get past No Session error in authentication process with Laravel 9/Angular 13 SPA?

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-9, angular13

I have my Angular 13 SPA authenticating to Laravel 9 (Sanctum). I'm able to get the CSRF cookie and perform the auth step, which is successful, but when I attempt to hit any other protected API endpoint I get a 'No Session' error. I've spent days going over all of the similar questions and I can't seem to track down a fix.

I have been able to determine that the session cookie I'm seeing on the Angular side does not match the session cookie on the server (Laravel) side of things, which I'm assuming is the issue. I'm just not sure what else to check.

I'm currently proxying /sanctum and /api through Angular so they both answer on localhost:4200.

I've tried several configs for my SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS values. All seem to work until I try and hit a protected route:

```
APP_URL=https://[assigned alias].ngrok.io
SESSION_DOMAIN=[assigned alias].ngrok.io
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=[assigned alias].ngrok.io

APP_URL=https://[alias].tunnelto.dev
SESSION_DOMAIN=.tunnelto.dev
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=[alias].tunnelto.dev

APP_URL=http://dev.local:4200
SESSION_DOMAIN=.dev.local
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=dev.local:4200

APP_URL=http://localhost:4200
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:4200
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Even more weird... If I comment out the SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS in .env then my session cookie values match, but once I hit a protected route I still get a 401 response with 'message: "Unauthenticated."'

Edit 2 (as requested by @Alexandru Ungureanu):
This is in my data service...

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }),
    withCredentials: true,
};

...

checkSession() {
    return this.http.post(apiUrl + '/session', {}, httpOptions);
}
```

Edit 3:

Continuing to do some troubleshooting of session cookies and it's behaving as I would expect it to. I'm logging the session cookie value from the browser and the server side to the console at each step, and they seem to match in pairs...

```
Browser Cookie between CSRF and Auth:
eyJpdiI6Ilk3M09RSU0zdVhae...

Server Cookie from Auth:
eyJpdiI6Ilk3M09RSU0zdVhae...

Browser Cookie between Auth and Session Check:
eyJpdiI6Ill1SWtOSlNXZytGQ...

Server Cookie from Session Check:
eyJpdiI6Ill1SWtOSlNXZytGQ...

Browser Cookie after Session Check:
eyJpdiI6InRrRlNodHVORXVtS...
```

Now why the Session Check fails as Unauthenticated when I make it a protected route is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I used santcum just once with angular and I had many issued but mainly because I had not followed the documentation well. From what you said it seems to me that the session token is reset. This is just a theory from someone who is just a junior so take it with a grain of salt. With sanctum I know that to authenticate you must first send a request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` and all the the following requests will automatically contain the csrf header. Make sure that you aren't sending another csrf request while you are authenticated because that will reset both the session and cookie if I remember correctly and cause a situation similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The CSRF piece is working... I get the XSRF-TOKEN cookie and Angular sends that back as the X-XSRF-TOKEN header in subsequent requests. I don't *think* the session is reset because it's maintained both in Angular and Laravel...the value of the laravel_session cookies just don't match.

Comment: So I'm watching the Cookie value in the Chrome Dev Tools and it appears that the Session cookie is getting set twice when I hit the login function in my PWA. I *think* the first set matches what the server retains, so it's starting to look like you are correct about the session getting reset.

Comment: Can you share the code in angular that takes you to the restricted area in laravel?

Comment: Is your SESSION_DRIVER set to file in ur .env? Also you don't need any of the headers beside withCredentials as angular takes care of that.